# How to change table attribute after printing it

Tags: php, css, html-table

I am using the following PHP code to print a table:

```
echo '<table> ';

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td> Cell 1';
echo '</td>';

echo '<td '.$myStyle.'> Cell 2';
echo '</td>';


echo '</tr>';

echo '</table> ';

$myStyle = 'style="color:red"';
```

My problem is the `$myStyle` cell attribute is not given to the cell unless if it is placed before it. Is there a way I can refresh the table after setting `$myStyle` so that the new attribute is taken? And I want it in a way where I keep my `$myStyle` variable.

Comment: This is possible using output buffering or JavaScript, but can't you change your script's logic to define `$myStyle` first? That would be the cleanest way.

Comment: why would you want to do that? why don't you just put $myStyle above echo '<table>';

Comment: @Pekka yes I know that is a solution, but I cant do that for reasons relating to further coding

Comment: Then you may have a construction problem that might be a good idea to fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jquery` OR `Javascript` on client side to accomplish this.

set an ID or class attribute of the target `td` then apply the following jquery like

html:

```
echo '<td id="mytd"> Cell 2 </td>';
```

jquery:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
$("#mytd").css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: can you give a little example

Answer (score 1):

If you don’t know which style settings to use for a cell when generating the table, then it would be best to modify the page generation, possibly using output buffering (a clumsy solution). Failing that, you could generate just, say, `<td class=foo>` in the markup and later on, when you know what you set for the cell, generate an HTML element like

```
<style>
.foo { color: red; }
</style>
```

This violates HTML syntax rules, as the `style` element will be inside the `body` element, but it actually works in browsers—settings in such an element have an effect on the document, even on elements preceding it.

But this is of course just an ugly workaround, for situations where a decent solution is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and you will see that

```
Notice: Undefined variable: myStyle in/ss.php on line 10
Cell 1  Cell 2
```

**put this variable to the top of the script**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$myStyle = 'style="color:red"';

echo '<table> ';

echo '<tr>';

echo '<td> Cell 1';
echo '</td>';

echo '<td '.$myStyle.'> Cell 2';
echo '</td>';


echo '</tr>';

echo '</table> ';
```